# Threaded discussions on a list item

Tags: comments

I've tried many different solutions to acheive comments on SharePoint.

The easiest is to add an append-only text field, but this doesn't allow for threaded discussion, i.e. replying to a specific comment, rather than endlessly adding to the general discussion.

One workaround I've found is to start with a discussion list, which already has those threaded comments. Is there any way to add them to list items ?